# Actionbar layout doesn't look right

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I am using this library:

https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip

However, my actionbar comes out looking like this:

[image]

I need it to look like this (notice the actionbar is no where near as big as mine):

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/master/art/material_tabs_middle.gif]

Here's my `activity_main.xml` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="56dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:textColorPrimary="@color/white"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/primary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsUnderlineHeight="0dp"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My `menu_main.xml` layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like you may have an additional Toolbar. Have you already added a Toolbar? Maybe you need to remove Toolbar from your RelativeLayout.

Comment: The only two layout files I have are `activity_main.xml` and `menu_main.xml` (the ones I posted) and I've tried changing both quite a bit, with no avail. I'm not sure what else or what other file could be the problem.

Comment: Did you call `setSupportActionBar(yourToolbar);` in `onCreate(Bundle)`? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)

Comment: That did it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have two Toolbar layouts in your Activity. You need to set the Toolbar using [`setSuppotActionBar(Toolbar)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)).

Example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```